# Forward Declaration of Class: Syntax Error

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, header-files, turbo-c++

I'm getting a declaration syntax error in the following code:

**fileio.h**

```
class fileio;  //ERROR HERE: I'm trying to declare it so I can use it in read() function
int read(char* file_1);   //File Read Function
```

**fileio.cpp**

```
int read(char* file_1) {   //File Read Function
    fileio Object_1;
    int records_read=0;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(file_1, ios::binary);   //Opens the file again

    while(fin.read((char*)& Object_1, sizeof(Object_1))) { 
        records_read++;
        Object_1.show_tablular();
    }
    fin.close();
    return records_read;
}
```

**Test.cpp**

```
template <class T>
void AddColumn(T data, const int& width) {
    cout<<setw(width)<<data<<" | ";
}

void Test_Class::show_tablular() {
    cout<<endl; AddColumn(record_id,7); AddColumn(char_member, 20); AddColumn(int_member, 11); AddColumn(float_member, 13);
}
```

inside main()

```
 class fileio : public Test_Class {   //Trying to relate the 2 classes
  public:
     void show_tablular() {
         Test_Class::show_tablular(); 
     }
};
```

I don't understand why it's happening...

Comment: What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: Show the lines before it also.

Comment: Forward Declaration can not let you make instance like `fileio Object_1;`.

Comment: Please do your self a favor and get a compiler from the current millenium.

Comment: How exactly do you expect your `fileio.cpp` to have any knowledge of the members of the class which is defined in a completely different translation unit, that may or may not even be compiled? In order to define `fileio Object_1;` you need to know more than just the class's name. The class must be fully declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declarations are fine for resolving pointer and reference types in declarations.

However, the compiler needs the complete definition of the types when compiling functions.